# Django Models from Across Apps

Tags: python, django

How do you access a model from across apps? For instance:

```
app:customers
-view:customerdetail model:customers table:tblCustomers 
app:reports
-view:reportdetail model:customers table:tblReports
```

[image: Structure]

**servicereport:urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views as servicereport_views

app_name = 'servicereport'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', servicereport_views.ServiceReportIndex.as_view(), name='servicereport_index'),
```

**servicereport:views.py**

```
    from servicesite.customers import models as servicereports_models
    from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView, View
    from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    from . import forms as servicereport_forms

class ServiceReportIndex(ListView):
    template_name = 'servicereport/servicereport_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_ServiceReports'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return servicereports_models.TblServiceRecords.objects.all().order_by("date_entered")
```

**Error**
    File "/path/to/project" in 
      1. from servicesite.customers import models as servicereport_models

```
Exception Type: ImportError at /servicereport/
Exception Value: No module named 'servicesite.customers'
```

**I've tried:**

```
from servicesite.customers import models as servicereports_models
from customers import models as servicereports_models
from ..customers import models as servicereports_models
```

among other things and each of those fail.

Comment: Is your `servicereport` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in `settings.py`?

Answer (score 0):

You were very close in your implementation.
Instead of importing 'model' just import the Model name from the models file.

Example:

```
from customers.models import <model name>
```

or

```
from servicereports.models import <model name>
```

If you want to import all of the models from a specific app, you can just use the * symbol to import everything, though this is never recommended.

Example:

```
from servicereports.models import *
```

Hope that helps!